# Why I cannot read all characters from a file in C++ using std::vector<char>

Tags: c++, file, csv

I wan t to read a large CSV file in c++, but reading in a  line by line manner is too slow for me (about 5M records). As I'm not sure about the delimiter in the file (, or space), I read the file char by char, convert to string, split all values and populate the array by converted values to doubles. My code is shown below, but it fails to read '\n' and ' ' chars? Would you please help me how can I read them. If there exist any faster and reliable way to read.

```
bool readPtFast(istream *dataIn, ANNpointArray &p) // read point (false on EOF)
{
    std::istream_iterator<char> begin(*dataIn), end;
    std::vector<char> in(begin, end);
    std::string wholeFileString(in.begin(), in.end()); // Not all chars are read!!


    std::vector<std::string> split_values_string;
    std::vector<double> split_values_double;

    boost::split(split_values_string, wholeFileString, boost::is_any_of("\n\r,;\t "));
    if (split_values_string.size()!=NRecords*NDims) {
        cerr << "Error reading file. I expected " << NRecords*NDims << " values, but I found " << split_values_string.size() << "records.\a";
        getchar();
        return false;
    }


    std::transform(split_values_string.begin(), split_values_string.end(), 
        std::back_inserter(split_values_double), 
        boost::lexical_cast<double, std::string>);

    std::copy(split_values_double.begin(),split_values_double.end(),*p);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: you can throw out a lot of unneeded (by the looks of it) processing by using `istreambuf_iterator<char>` instead of `istream_iterator<char>`. The former will just toss the checking and stream you chars. How big a file are we talking about here?? I see 5M records; does that mean 5M *doubles* or 5M *rows* ??

Comment: I'd take an `istream &`, not a pointer. It's easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `std::istream_iterator` will skip whitespace. Perhaps you could use the manipulator `std::noskipws` as described here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/noskipws/ or perhaps the `stream.unsetf(std::skipws)` method